# Convert function into plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a function that I call multiple times in my projects:

```
function fillSelect(select) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Data.asmx/Status",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.d, function(i) {
                select.append('<option value=' + data.d[i].value + '>' + data.d[i].name + '</option>');
            });
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert("Error occured. Contact admin");
        }
    });
}
```

Then in my code I'm using this like so:

```
fillSelect($('select#status1'));
fillSelect($('select#status2'));
fillSelect($('select#status3'));
```

What I would like to do is to convert my function into plugin, so I would be able to call it as so:

```
$('select#status1, select#status2, select#status3').fillSelect();
```

Using http://starter.pixelgraphics.us/ I've generated empty schema:

```
(function($) {
    $.ajaxSelect = function(el, select, options) {
        // To avoid scope issues, use 'base' instead of 'this'
        // to reference this class from internal events and functions.
        var base = this;

        // Access to jQuery and DOM versions of element
        base.$el = $(el);
        base.el = el;

        // Add a reverse reference to the DOM object
        base.$el.data("ajaxSelect", base);

        base.init = function() {
            base.select = select;

            base.options = $.extend({}, $.ajaxSelect.defaultOptions, options);

            // Put your initialization code here
        };

        // Sample Function, Uncomment to use
        // base.functionName = function(paramaters){
        // 
        // };

        // Run initializer
        base.init();
    };

    $.ajaxSelect.defaultOptions = {
        clear: false //append to select or replace current items
    };

    $.fn.ajaxSelect = function(select, options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            (new $.ajaxSelect(this, select, options));
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

but I don't know how to fill it.
What I would like to do is to call sever ones and then fill as many select items as I put in parameters.
Is all that code really necessary for such a small plugin?

**I know that there are probably some plugins that this functionality, but I would like to create my own plugin, just to learn a bit more :)**

Comment: you wish to fill all the selects with the same data? or how are you going to filter the data for each when sending just one request to the server?

Comment: yes, thats right, I would like to fill all selects with same data. So I think that only one request will be fine.

Comment: For a "select", I would create a string for the options, then only use one append (.html?) - that way you only hit the DOM once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all that boiler plate you could do as below

```
$.fn.fill = function fillSelect(options) {
   var self = this; 
   options = $.extend({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "Data.asmx/Status",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
               var list = "";
               $.each(data.d, function(i) {
                     list += '<option value=' 
                              + data.d[i].value + '>' 
                              + data.d[i].name 
                              + '</option>';
                  });
               self.filter("select").each(function(){
                   $(this).append(list);
               });
             },
            error: function(result) {
                alert("Error occured. Contact admin");
            }
          },options);
    $.ajax(options);
    return this;
}
```

the first thing to notice that the function is added to the jQuery prototype/$.fn. Then the success handler have been changed so that all selected elements will be handled and lastly the selection is returned to make chaining possible, as this is usually expect when using jQuery.

The above code will append the same options to all selected "select" elements only. If you select something else the options will not be appended to those elements.

I've changed the signature to accept an options element. In the above version there's default vesrion equaling your ajax options. If other values are supplied, they will override the default ones if a default exist. If a default does not exist the values will be added to the options object

Comment: But will this do only one request for multiple selects? Or for each select one request? 5 selects=5 requests to server?

Comment: @Misiu It will do just one request

Comment: I was trying to use Your code, when I use it like so: `$('select#myselect').fill()` I get error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'find'. Any ideas why?

Comment: there still is a bug in first line :) I think this is a bug.

Comment: @Misiu sorry there was a typo in the first line. (0 this)

Comment: there are still errors in Your code. I've fixed one of them, but still `find("select")` isn't working

Comment: there should be `filter` instead of `find` and `$(this).append(list)`. I was trying to do edits, but my changes were rejected. Please fix.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add your method to the `$.fn` object, as described here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

The `this` keyword will evaluate to the jQuery selector that was used to invoke your function's code, so instead of using the `select` parameter in your code, just use `this`